# Have to enter input twice rather than once to continue program

Tags: java, input

I'm writing a program for buying tickets. So far this is my code.

```
package prog;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class assign {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Which type of ticket do you require stand or terrace?");
        char tickType=sc.next().charAt(0);
        System.out.println("How many tickets do you require?");
        byte amount=sc.nextByte();
        if (amount<5)
            System.out.println("How many tickets for students?");
        byte stud=sc.nextByte();
        if (amount>=5)
            System.out.println("You are entitled to a 12% discount.");
        else if (stud>0)
        System.out.println("discount will be 10%");
        else
        System.out.println("You are not entitled to a discount");
    if (tickType=='S'||tickType=='s')
        System.out.println("Ticket cost is\t "+amount*20.00);
    else
        System.out.println("Ticket cost is\t"+(amount*15.00));
    double stand= amount*20.00;
    double terrace= amount*15.00;
    //VAT is 23%
```

When I get to

```
System.out.println("How many tickets do you require?");
        byte amount=sc.nextByte();
```

if I enter 5 or a higher number I have to enter it twice rather than once can somebody tell me why this is happening please?

Comment: The range of my test data fits in byte.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a flaw in the logic: if amount is less than five, then you print "How many tickets for students?", but then read the value *even if amount is greater or equal to five*.

The best solution would be to declare `byte stud = 0;` before `if (amount < 5)`, and then correct the if statement to include two lines:

```
byte stud = 0;
if (amount < 5) {
  System.out.println(...);
  stud = sc.nextByte()
}
```

This way, you read the value for stud only if amount is less than 5.

Answer (score 0):

You must be entering first value greater than 5. In this scenario it will not pass the condition `if(amount<5)` thus not printing s.o.p and expecting input because of next line which is `byte stud=sc.nextByte();`